# Applying Fourier Inversion Formula.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

Use the fourier inversion formula to evaluate  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.

I know that $\mathcal{F}(\frac{\sin(x)}{x})=c* \mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}$.

Now the fourier inversion formula states that: 
$\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\mathcal{F}(f))=f$ which implies that: 
$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{f}(\xi)\exp(-ix.\xi)d\xi$.

$\therefore$ I get the following: $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]} e^{-ix.\xi}d\xi$?

Have I approached the problem correctly?

Really appreciate the help! Thanks :)

Comment: what is c in this case?

Comment: @guy3141 c is just a constant.

Comment: It is the opposite. By direct calculation you know the Fourier transform of $1_{[-1,1]}$, from the Fourier inversion theorem you know the Fourier transform of $\frac{\sin x}x$ thus you know $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$

Comment: @reuns so I first compute the inverse fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$?

Comment: What you write doesn't make sense. Follow every step in my above comment.

Comment: @reuns I tried following your step. the fourier transform of $\mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}$ is $2\frac{\sin(i.\xi)}{i\xi}$ and the fourier transform of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is $c. \mathbb{1}_{[-1,1]}$. How does it give me the $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$?

Comment: It is not $2\frac{\sin(i.\xi)}{i\xi}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several normalizations for the Fourier Transform. I find the easiest to remember
$$
\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag1
$$
This normalization gives
$$
\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}(f))(x)=f(-x)\tag2
$$
Using $(1)$, it is easy to see that
$$
\mathcal{F}\!\left[\delta\!\left(x+\tfrac12\right)-\delta\!\left(x-\tfrac12\right)\right]\!(\xi)=e^{\pi i\xi}-e^{-\pi i\xi}\tag3
$$
Integrating $(1)$ by parts yields
$$
\mathcal{F}\!\left(f'\right)\!(\xi)=2\pi i\xi\,\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)\tag4
$$
Therefore,
$$\newcommand{\sinc}{\operatorname{sinc}}
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\!\left[-\tfrac12\le x\le\tfrac12\right]\!(\xi)
&=\frac{e^{\pi i\xi}-e^{-\pi i\xi}}{2\pi i\xi}\\[3pt]
&=\sinc(\pi\xi)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
where $[\cdots]$ are [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Since $\sinc$ is even, [Fourier Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) says
$$
\mathcal{F}(\sinc(\pi\xi))(x)=\left[-\tfrac12\le x\le\tfrac12\right]\tag6
$$
The scaling properties of the Fourier transform say
$$
\mathcal{F}(\sinc(\xi))(x)=\pi\left[-\tfrac1{2\pi}\le x\le\tfrac1{2\pi}\right]\tag7
$$
Now note that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\mathcal{F}(f)(0)$.

Comment: ♦ How does this use the fourier inversion formula?

Comment: In step $(6)$, as is stated. $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{F}(f))(x)=f(-x)=f(x)$ when $f$ is even.